# Undefined variable notice in a display.php error when the variable has eiher been fixed or deleted

Tags: php, dreamweaver, wampserver

I have 3 instances of

> Notice: Undefined variable (dog_title is an example of one, but there are two more)  of an "undefined variable: dog_title in
>   C:\wamp...display.php on line xx.

However, I changed the variable in the `sending.php` from `dog_title` to `dogTitle`, and then updated my variable in the `display.php` as well. I cleared my cache in Internet Explorer, but the notice still appears. I am using wampserver, with Dreamweaver CS6. I stopped and then restarted wampserver but this did not clear the notices. The `display.php` is not echoing the information from the `sending.php` for these variables.

in `sending.php`;

```
<form action="displaydogposting.php" method="post">
    <input name="dogTitle" type="text" id="dogTitle" value="" size="82" />
    <input name="dogKeywords" type="text" id="dogKeywords" size="82" />
    <textarea name="dogDescription" cols="80" rows="18" id="dogDescription"></textarea> 
</form>
```

in `display.php`;

```
<?php
    $dogTitle = $_POST['dogTitle'];
    $dogKeywords = $_POST['dogKeywords'];
    $dogDescription = $_POST['dogDescription'];
?>



<span>=<?php echo $dogTitle; ?></span><br />
<span>=<?php echo $dogKeywords; ?></span><br />
<span>=<?php echo $dogDescription; ?></span><br />
```

I have no loops or arrays. I only have variables defined for a form and then echoed. My id's and names match for all variables in my input fields on the `sending.php`, and the receiving php's variables match. I am using `POST`. The notice is coming from the `[main]()` function. I do not have my entire code listed but it is only nestled in `tables`, and therefore long and much of it has no bearing on this (at least I don't think it does)  I also have a print_r($_POST); which shows the results of the sending.php processing to the display.php, and only the variables mentioned above are not showing, but they are being passed.

Perhaps there is something specific about clearing the cache in IE that I am not doing. My files are updated and saved in Dreamweaver.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: var_dump($_POST). This will show you what is in your $_POST superglobal. If I remember correctly it will show you it as a key-value pair array. From there you can figure out what to call in your display

Comment: What does your `<form>` tag look like?

Comment: You are missing the `<?php` and `?>` tags around the first three lines in `display.php`

Comment: Yes those tags are there. I.apologize, I added them above along with my form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will be resolve your problem.

```
$value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
```

Comment: Yes I have seen that isset before. However I started up again today, restarting Dreamweaver and wamp and the problems above are gone now. Makes me think that there is a cache somewhere. That's OK, no problems now.